# How to construct a single graph for two completely different variables in terms of scale?

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, lattice

I have this data set

[image: data of Staff strength and total Applications received]

```
df <- data.frame(year = seq(1970, 2015, by = 5),
                 staff = c(219, 231, 259, 352, 448, 427, 556, 555, 602, 622),
                 applications = c(5820, 7107, 6135, 16119, 19381, 36611, 54962, 45759, 40358, 458582))
```

I want to perform the exploratory analysis and want to compare whether the staff strength is growing according to the applications received. I plotted a line graph using excel :
[image]

which isn't very meaningful.
I've also taken the log of both variables which almost got the desired result but i wonder if the graphs with log are less explainable to non-mathematicians. Since i want to use these kind of graphs in a presentation to my managerial staff who don't know much of statistics or mathematics.
My question is how to tackle this situation in order to draw a meaningful graph.
I've a gut feeling that R might have a better solution(that is why i asked here ) than Excel but the problem is 'How'?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: In `ggplot2`, you can use faceting with free_y.

Comment: Are you sure the last number in total application isn't a mistake or typo? In your plot, you can put an alternate y-axis for "santioned"  so that it is not compressed. You can compute the correlation.

Comment: @fishtank  .. It is not a mistake because online application system adopted in 2011 resulted in greater number of applications dramatically .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One recommendation would be to change your measure into some type of ratio metric. For example, `staff per applications`. In the following, I will use `staff per 1,000 applications`:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(year = seq(1970, 2015, by = 5),
                 staff = c(219, 231, 259, 352, 448, 427, 556, 555, 602, 622),
                 applications = c(5820, 7107, 6135, 16119, 19381, 36611, 54962, 45759, 40358, 458582))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = year, y = staff / (applications / 1000))) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("Staff per 1,000 Applications")
```

[image: Plot 01]

We can achieve the same result without `ggplot2` with:

```
with(df, 
      plot(x = year, y = staff / (applications / 1000), type = "l", main = "Staff per 1,000 Applications") + 
        points(x = year, y = staff / (applications / 1000), pch = 21, cex = 2, bg = "black")
     )
```

[image: Base R Plot]

---

Alternatively, you could make your dataset a little more tidy (see [this](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf), [this](https://ramnathv.github.io/pycon2014-r/explore/tidy.html), and/or [this](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/) for more information) and plot them two facets with `free_y` scales:

```
library(tidyr)

df_tidy <- gather(df, measure, value, -year)

ggplot(data = df_tidy, aes(x = year, y = value)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(measure ~ ., scales = "free_y")
```

[image: Plot 02]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `facet_grid` with `scales = "free_y"`.

```
ggplot(reshape2::melt(df, 1), aes(year, value)) + 
    geom_line() + geom_point() + 
    facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales = 'free_y')
```

The output you will get is,
[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
    we can use this process:



                  library(ggplot2)
                  library(reshape2)
                  ggplot(df, aes(year)) + 
                  geom_line(aes(y = staff, colour = "staff")) + 
                 geom_line(aes(y = applications, colour = "applications"))




             df <- data.frame(year = seq(1970, 2015, by = 5),
             staff = c(219, 231, 259, 352, 448, 427, 556, 555, 602, 622),
             applications = c(5820, 7107, 6135, 16119, 19381, 36611, 54962, 45759, 40358, 458582)
```